# Angular controller inheritance for mobile and desktop views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile

I have an application where each "component" has two views:  a mobile view and a desktop view.  These views are both similar enough where they should inherit a lot of code from the same place to stay DRY, but different enough where they should each have their own controller.

To remedy this, I have this setup:

Views

- Base template, "main.html" that uses ng-include to display either "mainMobile.html" or "mainDesktop.html"
- "mainMobile.html" for the mobile view, using ng-controller to specify the mobile controller
- "mainDesktop.html" for the mobile view, using ng-controller to specify the mobile controller

Controllers

- A base controller (MainCtrl)
- A controller that inherits from base and adds mobile-specific functionality (MainMobileCtrl)
- A controller that inherits from base and adds desktop-specific functionality (MainDesktopCtrl)

Take the MainMobileCtrl as an example.  It inherits from MainCtrl like so:

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainMobileCtrl', function ($scope, $controller) {
    var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope }));
});
```

This will pull in all of the properties set on the initial constructor call of MainCtrl.  Everything works all well and good, **until I start introducing asynchronous code.**

When the base controller (MainCtrl) adds or updates properties in the resolution of a promise, these changes are not pushed to the child controller (MainMobileCtrl):

```
angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, someService) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.notExposed = '---';

    someService.doThings().then(function () {
        vm.notExposed = 'unfortunately';
    });
});

angular.module('app').controller('MainMobileCtrl', function ($scope, $controller) {
    var vm = this;
    angular.extend(vm, $controller('MainCtrl', { $scope: $scope }));

    // just to illustrate that at this point, the service promise is resolved
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(vm.notExposed); // shows "---"
    }, 5000);
});
```

From what I can see, this is simply because the properties are copied over once into the `MainMobileCtrl.vm`, without any references.  I should mention that this seems to work with `$scope`, since it looks like the $scopes are shared by reference.  But I'd like to avoid using `$scope` in this way, as it then causes a confusing mismatch of `vm` and `$scope`'d variables.

Is there any *decent* way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between controllers, it is better to store this data is some service, and inject it to the controllers, where it should be used.
Also if you really need to implement OOP extension here, maybe you should do something like [it shown in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvladir/194pu19k/).

```
function extend(child, parent) {
    var F = function() { }
    F.prototype = parent.prototype;
    child.prototype = new F();
    child.prototype.constructor = child;
    child.superclass = parent.prototype;
}

function MainCtrl(){
   ...
}

extend(MainMblCtrl, MainCtrl);
function MainMblCtrl(){
   MainMblCtrl.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
   ...
}
```

Otherwhise you can use EcmaScript 6 or TypeScript, which have normal class-like extending.

Comment: Usually I would agree, but putting things into a service does not make sense for this case.  These are controllers that are driving UI's, not providing data.  For example, there could be a dropdown on the interface that is shared on both the desktop and mobile views -- this code would exist in the base controller and therefore the child controllers.  I don't want to duplicate code and have that dropdown functionality in each of the controllers, I just want it in the single base controller that the children inherit from.  It wouldn't make sense to put that in a service.

Comment: I updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvladir/194pu19k/1/) a bit. The data's stored in the controllers itself, and extension make the MobileController to behave the same as MainController. But in this case each controller's instance have it's own data's instances. So if you aren't going to share this data to the other application's parts, I think it will work for you.